# How do I align my boxes staggered underneath other boxes?

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Im fairly new to HTML and CSS.

I've got these 5 boxes, but I want to move the 2 boxes, underneath the top boxes so that there aligned in the space between.
[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzC0f.png)

Here my CSS is.

```
.box a{
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background: yellow;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: lightskyblue;
}
```

```
And here my HTML is.
<div class="box">
            <a th:href="@{info}">Info page</a>
            <a th:href="@{responsibility}">Responsibility page</a>
            <a th:href="@{what_we_do}">What we do</a>
            <a th:href="@{profile}">Profile</a>
            <a th:href="@{#}">Picture to come</a>
        </div>
```

Hope someone can help me figure out the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separate the rows in different divs
like this:

```
<div class="box">
       <div class="row1">
            <a th:href="@{info}">Info page</a>
            <a th:href="@{responsibility}">Responsibility page</a>
            <a th:href="@{what_we_do}">What we do</a>
       </div>
       <div class="row2">
            <a th:href="@{profile}">Profile</a>
            <a th:href="@{#}">Picture to come</a>
       </div>
   </div>
```

And make the second row flexible and give it `justify-content: space-between` like this:

```
.row2{
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between
}
```

Like this the flexible div child elements will take that div space in a flexible way and it will adapt considering the size of the parent div

Ill add you more info about "flex" display to make you understand it more deeply:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: You can try justify-content: space-around if you preffer. It will take same margin between the elements and around the borders

Comment: Hi Castle. Thanks for the input. So the idea is to have the class "box" just create the box itself, and than have row1 and row2 set the display position?

Comment: https://codepen.io/MichaeIMyers/pen/RwgmvXL
i prepared a sandbox for you

Comment: And you  should remove the margin-left if you use my solution, because you wont need it more

Comment: Great solution. Works nicely! More or less what im looking for. Only issue, now it's not centered

Comment: what div do you want to center? the container of all boxes?

Comment: I suppose it's the box div, that I want to center

Comment: .box {margin: 0 auto;} // If you liked my solution could you vote it? that will help other people with the same issue as you

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for all your help
Didn't know I could do margin: 0 AND auto. Do you have any good documentation for this?

Comment: of course: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/margin and you can use this documentation with other elements like: border or background. We can say that is an abbreviation of the attribute

Comment: Appreciate it! Thank you alot

Comment: Your welcome!. You can upvote the main answer too!